# run ajax call with a different parameter each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written a simple script that loads a content in a div every minute. The div content comes from a ajax call. The code I have is the following:

```
        setInterval(function() {
            $.get("scrollrtl.php?id=1", function(data){
                $('.messaggi').html(data);
            });
        }, 1000 * 60 * 1);
```

I have the following json array:

```
 [
Object { id="1", template="scrollrtl"},
Object { id="3", template="scrollrtl"}, 
Object { id="6", template="scrollrtl"}
]
```

How can I update my code so that each time I run the ajax call in the url instead of id=1 I can put one of the id in the array? 
So first time I will have

```
            $.get("scrollrtl.php?id=1", function(data){
                $('.messaggi').html(data);
            });
```

second time

```
            $.get("scrollrtl.php?id=3", function(data){
                $('.messaggi').html(data);
            });
```

and third time

```
            $.get("scrollrtl.php?id=6", function(data){
                $('.messaggi').html(data);
            });
```

To be more precise also the url (template in the array may change) but the logic is the same. The transition between each time is set by setInterval as every minute.

Comment: sorry @XGreen, didn't get it...

Comment: @LelioFaieta, I cant understand what are you trying to reach .. try to explain yourself better please. you'r trying to get the a specific row by implementing an ID of the current row you'r looking for ?

Comment: I have edited the question to be more precise. Can you see what I'd like to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// set an index that will be used to iterate through the array
var index = 0;

// make sure you use colons not equals signs in your object.
// your syntax was wrong
var arr = [
    { id:"1", template:"scrollrtl"},
    { id:"3", template:"scrollrtl"}, 
    { id:"6", template:"scrollrtl"}
];

// have a function that performs the action.
function doThing() {
  $.get("scrollrtl.php?id=" + arr[index].id, function(data){
      $('.messaggi').html(data);
  });

  // increase the index
  index++;

 // if the index is less than the length of the array
 // use a setTimeout (not setInterval) to call the function again
 // otherwise don't call the function again (obvs)
  if (index < arr.length) {
     setTimeout(doThing, 1000 * 60 * 1);
  }
}

// call doThing() to set the process going
doThing();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z0L5wn40/) -  the demo logs the object at the current index every second rather than a minute just as an example.

Comment: great. This does the trick. My array is coming from json_encode of a php array... how to turn = into : then?

Comment: That is an array of objects and that is how JavaScript objects are meant to be written. Your code won't parse if they're not colons. Sadly I don't know enough about PHP or json_encode to be able to help you. My guess is a change would need to be made on the server delivering the data.

Comment: so i think I can change index < arr.lenght with another kind of clause to stop the loop. For example i can check if the current timestamp is greater than a default one comiing from db?

Comment: If you wanted to, yes.

Answer (score 2):

**For Random Order**

```
var obj = [
    { id:"1", template:"scrollrtl"},
    { id:"3", template:"scrollrtl"}, 
    { id:"6", template:"scrollrtl"}
];


function getId(){
    return obj[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)].id;
}

setInterval(function() {
    $.get("scrollrtl.php?id=" + getId(), function(data){
        $('.messaggi').html(data);
    });
}, 1000 * 60 * 1);
```

**For sequential order**

```
var obj = [
    { id:"1", template:"scrollrtl"},
    { id:"3", template:"scrollrtl"}, 
    { id:"6", template:"scrollrtl"}
]


var index = 0;
setInterval(function() {    
    $.get("scrollrtl.php?id=" + obj[index].id, function(data){
        $('.messaggi').html(data);
    });
    index++;
    index == obj.length ? index = 0 : false;
}, 1000 * 60 * 1);
```

Comment: *1 is just for test. Then it will become a parameter configured by the sysadmin and can be any number...

Comment: Looks like the OP wants the items in order rather than at random.

Comment: yes. The array is defined by the sysadmin with a specific order. It is a sequence of messages each with its text (given by the id) and displayed using a template (given by the other value in the array